# Weblogic : Log errors in a specific log file for a managed server

Tags: logging, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, error-logging

For a given managed server (not a whole weblogic server), I need to copy / reroute all WARNING, ERROR, INCIDENT_ERROR level messages to a log file (that has to have rotation settings). Let's say "server1.err.log".
The rest of the messages (level under WARNING) have to be written in a different file, for example, "server1.log".

How can I do that ? My Weblogic server version is 10.3.6.0.
I also asked this question in OTN without successfully getting an acceptable response..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using WebLogic log facilities (so the logs are in <domain>/servers/<MyServer>/logs or are you logging in a dedicated folder with another logging framework?

Comment: @foch I use the `<domain>/servers/<MyServer>/logs` folder, with a custom `logging.xml` configuration, but I can change everything on this configuration. All I want is all error level (and above) messages in a file, and info level (and less) messages in another one. I am also ok to have a file with everything in it (like native `server1.log`) and another one with a copy of all error level messages.

Comment: Do you want to filter applicative logs, or are you interested by WebLogic middleware logs as well?

Comment: I do need errors from Weblogic and from my application.

Comment: Then I don't have any solution for you... I personally use SLF4J/logback for my applicative logs, and with it it's possible to use "thresholds" to achieve what you want. WebLogic uses java.util.logging for which I have less experience!

Comment: @foch Thank you anyway. I already have my application errors in a dedicated file, but I wanted to have __ALL__ errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is your answer, finally found the missing piece of the puzzle to very obscure Weblogic Loggin Service architechture.

To get what you want you need to do the following:
(1) Read through the following documentation piece
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13739/listening.htm#WLLOG188

(2) Then using weblogic specific Jars, code your own Log4J Appender or Jul Handler

(3) Make sour appender subscribe on the Weblogic Server logger. The server logger of weblogic is just a shell that is being route logging events from deployed applications as well as weblogic internal code - such as when your code blows up and the EJB container logs and error.

(4) Code into your handler whatever logic you want.

I will not provide you my design architechture for this, but I will give you an extra two scents:

Be very careful on how your appender logs events coming from weblogic.
Make sure that whatever your Appender does for logging the Weblogic WARNINGs or Weblogic INFOS or Errors does end up creating new logging events to the weblogic server logger, or you will create an infinite recursive loop of logging and posisbly even dead lock the logging framework.

But this is the solution for what you want to do - nothing else with work on the Admin Console - you have to realize the weblogic logging architechture is like a closed rock that wants to swallow all the log events and present yoiu the not so useful console log overview of those log events.

I personally do not like it, I think its obscure, but at least you have a way to plugin your own to code their logging architechture.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

you have to customize the log location whenever you build the managed server...

If that task not yet done no issue...we can achieve that tasks via admin console

Do following stuff...

1.Logon to admin console and Lock and Edit

2.Open the node(admin or managed for which you want to configure logs)

3.Go to Logging tab

4.give a proper location in log file name filed

5.Save and Activate the changes

For more detailed diagrammatic information...please check the below link

http://biemond.blogspot.in/2011/07/change-log-files-location-of-weblogic.html

Comment: Hi, thank for replying, But I think you did not understand my request. I do need to have, in one hand, INFO (or less) level messages, and in the other hand, ERROR (or above) level messages. I am ok if the first log file contain everything.

Comment: I minused your answer because is ten miles off the mark. What he wishes to be able to do is something like you are able to do in a normal log4j.properties or logging.properties for java util where you could configure muliple loggers or appernds with different target files. The wbelogic console logging is quite quite limited. Is like a slugish stone UI and geting proper logging and with a proper format, is a daunting task. What you suggest does not help at all on his task.  I cannot help you yet ... I am also investigating weblogic logging and geting more and more disapointed by the second.